# ViewStart and Layout - what's the difference?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-layout

I have just started reading ASP.NET MVC 4 book and got one question. In the Razor part author said that if i dont set the Layout variable in the View.cshtml file it will as default search for a _ViewStart.cshtml, but in another part he is using _Layout.cshtml in Views/Shared, I dont get it.

If i got smth like this in View.cshtml :

```
@{
     Layout = null;
 }
```

It tells that that this View has no layout, but if i make it like :

```
@{

 }
```

So this will make that the View will search for a _ViewStart.cshtml file or _Layout.cshtml?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Basically by default we have master layout in **Views>> Shared >> _Layout.cshtml** and this thing is defined in **_ViewStart.cshtml** that which one is our default master layout.

When we create a  view with master layout by default its master layout is **_Layout.cshtml**, but we can change it from **_ViewStart.cshtml**

When we write:

```
@{
     Layout = null;
 }
```

in our view we say that this view does not have any master layout, this is used when we create partial view mostly or a standalone view without master layout.

If you open **_ViewStart.cshtml** by default it has this written in it:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

and we can change it if we want to.

You can also change of some specific view Master Layout by writing on top of it the url of master layout view:

```
@{
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_CustomMasterLayout.cshtml";
 }
```

Comment: Ohh gosh, nvm I noticed that he started using Layout and was like "WTF he said that empty layout will search for a ViewStart" and I have just noticed that there is also ViewStart one folder before... :D Thank you !:)

Answer (score 1):

You can set it to default (as he has done in the second example) or make your own 'custom' one (which he will probably do from now on).

The author will probably go into more/better detail once you have learnt a bit more (creating layout sheets/etc).

Comment: My problem is, if i leave View without setting Layout like the second snippet, then it will search for a _ViewStart.cshtml or _Layout.cshtml? ;d

Comment: _Layout.cshtml. The ViewStart will only be used on the first page for default. Layout otherwise.(from what I recall).

Comment: Nono its like Ehsan said, every View that has not setted Layout variable is searching for a _ViewStart.cshtml

Comment: Sorry! Tbh I didn't really mess with the layout part, as there are different bootstrap 'themes' that are very useful in changing the way your website looks. But that's for another day!